# How to debug an unstable connection in a P2P configuration

Tags: networking, router, hardware-failure, arp

have a setup where I have two computers connected to each other (C1 and C2). Both have a static IP and they know each others IP. C2 sends UDP packets to C1 and C1 receives and logs them.

Seems simple but here is the catch: There is about 1 kilometer of coax cable connecting those two devices. The connection between C1 and C2 is through a ethernet over coax converter which also transfers PoE. C2 is at a remote location and the only connection is a COAX wire.

The setup seems to work at times, I have had it running for several hours. But then at another time, without changing the configuration, the connection seems to become unstable. Since it looked like a connection issue I used wireshark to see what is being transmitted over the network.

When the system is running ok I can see all the packages from C2 reaching C1. When there are connection issues I can see that C2 is broadcast the command

```
Who has ip ip addr C1 - tell ip addr C2
```

This feels like it has lost it's connection. To verify that it is not a power issue I have checked the uptime of C2 and this is OK. It has been running continuously over the connection problems.

I am trying to figure out what causes this connection problems. The questions I have at this point are:

1. When does an device emit the 'Who has IP' message?
2. What tests can I do to check to establish if it is a software or hardware issue?

Final comment: I have placed a router between the devices on the C1 side. The connecting outages till occur but it seems to be less frequent. Is a router able to stabilize connections like these?

**Update:**
I managed to find the [specsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoWSC.png) of the cable we are using.

Comment: How long is the time frame it drops?

Comment: It seems not to be a specific time. Sometimes it seems to go on for several hours and some times it can't reastablish the communication for several minutes.

Comment: whats the cable rating you have installed? is this RG59u? it should be listed on the cable.

Comment: We use non-standard cable. A reinforced 50 ohm Coax. Also nonstandard characteristics but similar to a RG58

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially I was thinking the same thing as Carlos. but ARP aging would account for brief ping loss, and not minutes or hours of no connectivity.

Coax cable systems compared to others are considered high maintenance. The reason for this is that connectors are usually exposed to the weather. Proper grounding is also paramount to keeping signal to noise ratios within manufacturers specifications.

1. Inspect all connectors indoor and outdoor looking for any corrosion, or oxidization on intermediary connectors. A good terminated connector should have 0.3db to 1.0db of loss (this includes any "barrel" or "double female" connectors.) As connectors age and are exposed to high humidity etc, they become oxidized, oxidization where metal meets for a connection causes higher ohmic resistance (DC) and higher impedance (AC resistance). Both apply here as your adapters also send 55vdc over the coax, and high frequency AC for communication. with oxidization, connectors can easily reach 1.5db loss per connector. (2 connectors @ -1.5 = -3db = 50% signal loss) this can completely break a link of this type.

Bad Cable that has oxidization on the center pin, and should be cut off & re-terminated.
[image]

Good bright center-pin.

[image]

In my experience the best thing you can do on either end is use high quality compression fittings to terminate these cables. (see below) they will last a considerable amount more time then their cheap counter-parts, and when terminated properly have little loss in comparison.
[image]

2. Inspect each ends grounding. grounding is paramount in center coax connections, and ideally the block itself should be oxidization free. and so should the copper terminating to the grounding block.
3. Make sure you match connector impedance with cable impedance. If the cable is 50ohm, get 50ohm connectors.

Without knowing what cable you are actually using, its hard to tell you if its in spec at this distance. but here is what i found in the data-sheet.

Low-q CATV wiring = 800m or 2624.67ft

RG/59u            = 2500m or 8202.1ft

RG-6              = 3500m or 11482.94ft

RG-11             = 5000m or 16404.2ft

I did notice in the datasheet that these adapters have a limited lifetime warranty. if you clean up the connectors/grounding and it still isn't stable. I would have the manufacture replace them.

If you are terminating yourself. Give this link a read. 
https://www.belden.com/blog/digital-building/13-common-bnc-connector-installation-mistakes

Comment: Thank you for the clear and extensive explanation about COAX wires. I have added the specsheet of the cable to my question. After investigating more it seems that this is a hardware issue. We have several connectors, one is a slip contact (non coax). On top of that there were some non-coax wires in the setup. Right now we are trying to eliminate all these possible disturbances

Comment: You are welcome. That is an excellent place to start troubleshooting.

Comment: As it turns out it was the coax connection. The bottleneck was the quality of the coax cable. The hardware was unable to transmit over such a long distance with the quality of coax we used.

Answer (score 1):

Connection between the two systems using IP(L3) goes over ethernet(L2).
To be able to send something to C1 (IP address), C2 has to find the ethernet address (MAC) of C1. That's done using ARP (a dedicated protocol) which in turn uses broadcast to reach C1, thus obviating the need to know C1's MAC.

The system keeps a table of IP - MAC mappings, and those entries last some time (5 minutes?). When they "age" out, ARP is called again. (if needed to keep talking to some device, C1 in this case).

That answers your Q1.

Q2 is more complicated.... what kind of coax converter are you using ? Is it able to drive 1km ? I guess that going to the remote site and seeing there with wireshark if you are receiving the packets should be conclusive, but my hunch is that you are pushing the limits of the equipmnent.

After looking at the specs of the device you are using (NV-EC1701) this is the range depending on the cable type and power delivered:
[image]

If the cable is "like" an RG/59U (note the device says it supports 25-100ohms cables) then for a 6W remote you are on its limits.

Comment: Thank you for the arp explanation. I did not realise they could "age" out. Would a static arp entry help in this case?

Comment: As for the Q2, I am using an [NVT EC1701](http://www.nvtphybridge.com/portfolio-item/nv-ec1701/#tab-id-5). And indeed its pushing the limits of the equipment. But what I don't understand is why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work. And ultimately, what should be changed to make it work.

Comment: A static ARP will not help, because the ARPing is not your problem. Your problem is that data is not getting through both ways, so ARP is not able to resolve. Even with a static ARP entry, your actual data would not come through either.

Comment: The specs actually say that it can work up to 2.5 kms. This sounds like hardware issue to me. It might be noise, lack of good grounding, bad power, ... put another PC on the other side and find out with wireshark. But if it sometimes work, your changing the device can change the situation.

Comment: @Carlos, Where are you getting these figures? In most applications RG-58 would have HIGHER signal loss compared to RG-59U. The truth is neither one of us knows for a fact this is in spec, the OP didn't state the category of cable. Post instructions to troubleshoot with wire-shark for the OP please, I am interested to see how you troubleshoot a layer-1 problem with a higher level tool. the only way i know of trouble shooting these systems is an expensive digital analyzer, and or time domain reflection for finding breaks in the cable/shielding.

Comment: The 2.5 kms is in the device specs. I've not mentioned type of cable anywhere. And he already knows how to use wireshark, cause he says he did on one end.

Comment: The pic shows distance reach depending on power transmitted and cable type. Same cable, more power drain gives less distance.
Then, if it works at layer 2, it means layer 1 is operational. I know you need layer 1 instruments to troubleshoot that, but a works/does not work is easy and separates software from hardware issues, which was the question asked.

Comment: The picture comes from the [ethernet to coax converter manual](http://www.nvtphybridge.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/NV-EC1701_Complete_Manual-Nov17.pdf) page 9. Investigating the problem and the answers I got here make it more likely that it is a hardware issue...